# Cron job limitations

Tags: php, cron

Id like to run a cron job once a week which runs a php script.

The script will need to get all users from a database and run another script which sends each user an email with a report with data pulled from an external API.

The problem is, there is a 100mb memory limit on every cron job.  If there are thousands of users in my db and I need to retrieve lots of data from the external API I will soon exceed the memory limit.

Is there a way to work around this by breaking up the php scripts?  What would your strategy be?

Comment: I assume your crond will not force this memory limit just for fun, so you should not be able to get around it by issuing subprocesses. Do you have command line access to the machine? You could then write a small script that does nothing but execute the job, sleep a week, do the job, sleep a week... This should not waste too much resources

Comment: i guess there's some problem in your `php` code: it must not consume 100MB for sending mails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to break up the script, you can leave the weekly cron but instead of sending mails you can queue it into a database table. Then, using a second cron that run every 5 or 10 minutes, you can read the database mail queue (searching for max 50 or 100 rows) and if you find something, you send a chunk of emails...

In general, this strategy (huge queue loading, smaller queue processing in chunks) allow you to split execution of large processes.

Answer (score 4):

Do you run the cron job via cli or via a php page?
Try running it via cli with

```
php -d memory_limit=256M yourscript.php
```

or set the memory limit in your php.ini

check this for more http://blog.urbaninsight.com/comment/1544

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`ini_set`](http://fr.php.net/ini_set) to bump the `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` (ususally infinite in command though).

example:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // <-- infinite
```